# Find the sum of roots of the polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the zeros of a quadratic polynomial, what is the value of $\alpha - \beta$ ?

I have to find the answer in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial and I have to use the formulas $\alpha + \beta = -b/a,\alpha\cdot\beta=c/a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha,\beta$ are the roots of the polynomial
$$ p(x)=x^2-sx+p = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\tag{1}$$
we have $s=\alpha+\beta, p=\alpha\beta$ (Viète's formulas). It follows that:
$$ (\alpha-\beta)^2 = (\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta = s^2-4p\tag{2} $$
so the distance between the roots is the square root of the discriminant.

Comment: What if i use the quadratic formula? 
Then i get the answer, square root of the discriminant /a ?

Comment: @AaryanDewan: that is another chance for sure.

Comment: So , what would i write in the exam paper? 
Your method or the quadratic one?

Comment: @AaryanDewan: the choice is yours, but since the problem suggests to use Viète's formulas, it may be the case to actually use them.